# (PowerShell) Rename multiple files to include "MM_YYYY", "File 1 in XX" and "number of lines"

Tags: powershell

How can I rename multiple files in a folder to include :

- MM_YYYY
- File 1 in XX
- Number of lines in the file

Example :

Current file name :

- SRA_0400041325.TXT
- SRA_0400027561.TXT
- SRA_0400013497.TXT

After :

- SRA_0400041325_03_2022_1-3_720.TXT
- SRA_0400027561_03_2022_2-3_433.TXT
- SRA_0400013497_03_2022_3-3_1720.TXT

How to do that in PowerShell ?

Thanks.

**EDIT 1 :**

I've tried this :

```
$Month = (Get-Date).ToString("MM")
$Year = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy")
$MonthYear = $Month + "-" + $Year

$NumberOfFiles = (Get-ChildItem | Measure-Object).Count

$NumberOfLines =  Get-Content SRA_0400041325.TXT | Measure-Object -line | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Lines


$PartToAdd = $MonthYear + "_" + $NumberOfFiles + "_" + $NumberOfLines
Write-Host $PartToAdd
```

But I don't know how to include a ForEach

Comment: What have you tried and how did that fail, or how did the result differ from what you expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've found, you can use `Get-ChildItem` to discover the files and `Get-Content` to enumerate the contents and count the lines.

Now you just need a variable to keep track of which number file you're currently processing:

```
# Prepare the date parts
$Month = (Get-Date).ToString("MM")
$Year = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy")

# Discover the files
$Files = @(Get-ChildItem -File)
$NumberOfFiles = $Files.Count

# We'll use this to keep track of which number file we're operating on
$FileCounter = 1

foreach($file in $files){
  $NumberOfLines = ($file |Get-Content |Measure-Object -Line).Lines

  # Construct the file-count part
  $FileCountString = $FileCounter,$NumberOfFiles -join '-'

  # Remember to update the file counter
  $FileCounter++

  # Construct the new file name
  $newName = $file.BaseName,$Month,$Year,$FileCountString,$NumberOfLines -join '_'

  # Rename the file
  $file |Rename-Item -NewName $newName
}
```